# How to fix `cannot be cast to java.lang.String` in RN?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I got this error in my RN application in Android:

> 06-06 16:37:54.455 7506-7569/system_process E/AudioTrack: Could not
>   get audio output for session 729, stream type -1, usage 13, sample
>   rate 48000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x3, flags 0x4 06-06 16:37:54.455
>   7506-7569/system_process E/SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack 06-06
>   16:37:54.924 1286-1286/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1286:
>   eglCreateSyncKHR(1669): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE) 06-06
>   16:37:55.190 11821-11894/com.efiat_rn E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception
>   in native call
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getString(ReadableNativeMap.java:168)
>           at com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule.showAlert(DialogModule.java:232)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 06-06 16:37:55.191 11821-11894/com.efiat_rn E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native
>   call
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getString(ReadableNativeMap.java:168)
>           at com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule.showAlert(DialogModule.java:232)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

It runs perfectly fine on iOS version. It don't show me which JS I do wrong. and I have no clue or ideas on how to fix it. It prompts when I launch the application, when I dismiss the error message, I can see a half-load application, but not clickable. Is there any ideas on how can I start the debugging? Thanks.

Comment: any updates on this? Were you able to debug this?

Answer (score 8):

In ReactNative you are calling a method of the native bridge which requires String parameters. But what you are actually sending is JsonObject.

Example,

```
const data = {message: "hello"};   // Consider this as your data
```

if you send this to the bridge, it will create a NativeArray and send it to native layer (But your layer's method expects String).

Now you have to convert the object to String and send it to the native layer

```
const strData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Now send the strData to the native layer

> (Comment below if you need more details or you can tell your error
>   more clearly to get some clear answer)

Comment: I see. I would like to provide more details, but in the error message, I don't know which file or which line or even any hints to find out which place of code is doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post your NativeLayer(Java class you have written) in Android side?